# Referencing Public Viewcontroller.cs from another Class using Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I am new to IOS design. I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin.IOS to create a app. I have the default Viewcontroller.cs that is the code-behind class for the Viewcontroller. I have another class that needs to read and write to this Viewcontroller's Methods or Controls. I assume i would need to create a new instance but not sure how, because the structure is new to me:

```
 public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{    
    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

    }
```

Im not sure what to pass ?

```
ViewController vc = new ViewController(?);
```

I am a long time VB programmer and just learning C#.

Comment: What you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way of instantiating a viewcontroller is:

```
ViewControllerClassName viewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController(nameof(ViewControllerClassName )) as ViewControllerClassName;
```

you would then use the object 'viewController' to access any public methods within that view controller, or to pass to the navigation stack as such:

```
NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, true)
```

Comment: Had to add:  UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);  But there is no access to any labels on the viewcontroller. Get a null reference when trying to set their .text. ?

Comment: you could try creating a public accessor to the controls, in the viewcontroller you're trying to get to the controls in. so create a public UIControl variable for the class and assign your control to it in viewdidload. Similar to how you would create the prototype cells for a tableviewcontroller

Comment: I recently completed a 6 hour online C# course and it appears this would be the only way to do it. In VB we never had to instantiate a Form and they were always available through direct calling.